# Convert Oracle Regexp_replace function into Netezza

Tags: regex, oracle, netezza

Following `Regexp_replace` needs to be converted into Netezza Syntax:

```
regexp_replace(COLUMN_NAME,'([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)|(\s+$)',null)
```

From what i understand, 
`cntrl` replaces control characters
`^\t` replaces tabs
`\s+$` replaces trailing spaces

Please help!
Please also correct my understanding of what this current regex does in oracle.

Comment: `^\t` replaces only one tab (rather than "tabs") and only if it is the very first character in the string (the meaning of `^`). Is this some code written by someone else that you want to translate to a different language? If you are not sure what it does, why do you need to translate it?

Comment: yeah! someone else wrote it. I need it because I need the exact functionality in Netezza

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right.

```
([[:cntrl:]])|(^\t)|(\s+$)
```

1. `[:cntrl:]` — matches control characters
2. `\t` — matches tab
3. `^\t` in between expressions — matches a `^` and tab character together
4. `[^\t]` in between expressions — matches non-tab characters
5. `^\t` at start — matches leading tab characters
6. `\s+$` — matches text with trailing spaces

Effectively, your expression will match - first control character, leading tab or trailing spaces.

Comment: thanks! That helps. Any info on the Netezza Conversion part?

Comment: What is Netezza syntax? Could post some example in the question

Comment: This regex replace function is not working in netezza! So I want to convert it into a function or set of functions which perfrom the same replace as this one but in Netezza. For example:
oracle: regexp_replace(column,'a','A') netezza: translate(column,'a','A')

Comment: You need to install the [SQL extensions toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqltk_plg_overview.html). Then the function is the same: `regexp_replace`.

Comment: @Jeremy, Thanks, I have that installed but the arguments passed to the function seem to work differently. Like in my case, if I execute the same regex as mentioned initially in the question, a NULL output is being returned